# What is the easiest way I can transition an image/element to another image/element while dragging it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can transition the sun to another image while dragging it? And if so what is it and what language should I use? I want to transition the sun to another darker sun which transitions into a moon while I am dragging it. Right now I am able to drag my sun in an arc.
http://whatisupson.tumblr.com/

This is my code:

```
    <style>
        /* Colors */
        body {
             background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
             animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes mymove {
            0% { background-position: 0 0; }
            50% { background-position: 40% 0; }
        }
        #sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 20%;
            left: 10%;
        }
    </style>

    <html>
    <body>
            <img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var width = 300;
    var sun = $("#sun");

    sun.draggable({
        axis: "x",
        drag: function() {
            var x = sun.offset().left + (width / 2);
            var total = $(window).width();

            var heightPct = Math.pow((total/2) - x, 2) / Math.pow($(window).width() / 2, 2);
            console.log(x, $(window).width(), heightPct * 100);
            this.style["margin-top"] = "" + Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";
        }
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/twfegqgc/3/

I am using background color on element and the color changes on element position. So the color changes when element passes half of window and when it reach end of window. You can set image change instead but it's same principle.

JS

```
var sun = $("#sun");
var width = 100;

sun.draggable({
        axis: "x",
        drag: function() {
            var x = sun.offset().left + (width / 2);
            var total = $(window).width();

            var heightPct = Math.pow((total/2) - x, 2) / Math.pow($(window).width() / 2, 2);
            console.log(x, $(window).width(), heightPct * 100);
            this.style["margin-top"] = "" + Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";
        }
    });

$("#sun").bind("drag", function(event, ui) {
    var halfWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left + 100;
    var windowWIdth = $(window).width() - 200;
    var color = $('.color');

    $('.position').html(left);
    $('.window').html(windowWIdth);

    if(left < halfWidth) {
        color.css('background', 'yellow');
    }

    if(left > halfWidth) {
        color.css('background', 'red');
    } 

     if (left > windowWIdth) {
        color.css('background', 'black');
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="sun" class="color"></div>
<div class="position"></div>
<div class="window"></div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
         background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
         animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
         -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
         -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes mymove {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        50% { background-position: 40% 0; }
    }
    #sun {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        top: 20%;
        left: 10%;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }

    .color {
        background: yellow;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Updated version with `background-image` https://jsfiddle.net/twfegqgc/4/

Comment: Would it work if I replaced " var color" with "var image" and add images instead of colors?

Comment: I think it will if you use  `image.css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)"); ` but i think image must be local you cant pull image from net like you did here ` <img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">`. That is the reason why i was using background color

Comment: I replaced "color" with "image", but the sun isn't budging. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/60232e6ec6c3015f84ac

Comment: Like i said image should be from your directory not from online url.

Comment: Yes that is what I did. Can you revise my code from the link I gave? I need to see what I did wrong, and I am not sure why it's not working.